# Salvar informações de abas

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, angularjs, entity-framework-6

Tenho minha tela, da seguinte forma:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

cada aba corresponde a uma classe, e entidade do banco de dados,
e indo na sequencia existe uma referencia delas, ou seja

na 02 tem referencia(fk) da 01, na 03 tem referencia(fk) 02 e assim por diante.

Eu até então sempre salvava e retornava o id salvo para quando mudar de aba ele ter o id(fk) e poder salvar.

Entretanto se o usuário cancelar, iria ficar um registro lá vago, além de ele não poder pular as abas, tem que ir sempre em sequencia.

Alguém pode me dar uma ideia de como resolver isso?

Pode ser usando angularjs

Answer (score 1):

Se seus modelos usam `Guids`, a solução fica natural.

Suponha os seguintes modelos:

```
public class ModeloPrincipal
{
    [Key]
    public Guid ModeloPrincipalId {get; set; }
}

public class ModeloAba1
{
    [Key]
    public Guid ModeloAba1Id {get; set; }
    public Guid ModeloPrincipalId {get; set; }

    public virtual ModeloPrincipal ModeloPrincipal { get; set; }
}

public class ModeloAba2
{
    [Key]
    public Guid ModeloAba2Id {get; set; }
    public Guid ModeloPrincipalId {get; set; }

    public virtual ModeloPrincipal ModeloPrincipal { get; set; }
}

public class ModeloAba3
{
    [Key]
    public Guid ModeloAba3Id {get; set; }
    public Guid ModeloPrincipalId {get; set; }

    public virtual ModeloPrincipal ModeloPrincipal { get; set; }
}
```

Quando o modelo principal já existe, você usa uma chave provisória para referenciar na criação:

```
public ActionResult Create() 
{
    var modeloPrincipal = new ModeloPrincipal();
    modeloPrincipal.ModeloPrincipalId = Guid.NewGuid();

    modeloPrincipal.ModeloAba1 = new ModeloAba1 {
        modeloPrincipalId = modeloPrincipal.ModeloPrincipalId;
    };

    modeloPrincipal.ModeloAba2 = new ModeloAba2 {
        modeloPrincipalId = modeloPrincipal.ModeloPrincipalId;
    };

    modeloPrincipal.ModeloAba3 = new ModeloAba4 {
        modeloPrincipalId = modeloPrincipal.ModeloPrincipalId;
    };

    return View(modeloPrincipal);
}
```

A geração das chaves fica toda ao critério do programador. O banco apenas recebe a informação. Não há preocupação com geração de chave primária `IDENTITY` e não há necessidade de trabalhar com chaves provisórias.

Na hora de salvar, um único `SaveChanges()` faz tudo.

Agora, se seus modelos usam chaves primárias `int` com `IDENTITY`, você vai ter salvar o registro principal já na primeira mudança de aba, juntamente com o primeiro registro da aba, a não ser que o usuário cancele a ação já na primeira aba. Considero que para um sistema usando AngularJS isto seja bem ruim.